# File not found when executing script as admin

Tags: vbscript, permissions, admin, hta

I have this script that launches an HTA which needs to be started with admin rights.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

isLocal = MsgBox("Launch app for a local configuration ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Settings")
If isLocal = vbYes Then
    objShell.Run "src\Configurator.hta"
Else
    'This code doesn't matter here
End If
```

This script runs fine when started normally, but when I execute the VBS as Administrator (via context menu), I get a File Not Found error for the *objShell.Run "src\Configurator.hta"* line.

When I add the following code, it gives the same result for both executionning methods (gives the directory where the script is executed).

```
scriptdir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
MsgBox scriptdir
```

Any help or explanation on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is a working directory issue. Open a cmd as admin, navigate to the script location and execute it. Or eventually, use `objShell.Run scriptdir & "\src\Configurator.hta"`

Comment: Both your solutions work but my HTA doesn't get admin rights.

In my HTA I have a sub that check for admin rights and it says it doesn't, and my methods that needs admin rights doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this : [Procedure to run HTA elevated](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/procedure-to-run-HTA-308b5995)

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>HTA Helpomatic</title> 

<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="oHTA" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTAHelpomatic" 
     SCROLL="yes" 
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" 
> 
<!-- ID="objHTAHelpomatic" --> 
<!-- WINDOWSTATE="maximize" --> 

</head> 

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 

If HTAElevate() = True Then 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mmc.exe compmgmt.msc", , True 
    Call Main() 
End If 

Sub Main() 
    MsgBox "HTA-Ende", 4096 
End Sub 


'*** v13.3 *** www.dieseyer.de ***************************** 
Function HTAElevate() 
'*********************************************************** 
' Unter Windows x64 laufen VBS' nach einem Doppelklick in der x64-Umgebung 
' mit %WinDi%\System32\wscript.exe oder mit %WinDi%\System32\cscript.exe. 
' In der x64-Umgebung laufen VBS aber nicht (richtig). Die Prozedur 
' HTAElevate() erkennt dies und startet ggf. das VBS in der 

  Const Elev = " /elevated" 

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5016 :: " 

' Trace32Log "5018 :: oHTA.commandLine: ==" & oHTA.commandLine & "==", 1 

  HTAElevate = True 

' If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5022 :: " 
  If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then Exit Function 


  On Error Resume Next 
    window.resizeto 750, 10 ' : window.moveto screen.width / 2, screen.height / 2 
  On Error GoTo 0 

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5030 :: " 

  createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", oHTA.commandLine & Elev, "", "runas", 1 

  HTAElevate = False 

  self.close 

End Function ' HTAElevate() 


</SCRIPT> 
<body> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used both yours and Cid answer to solve my issue. I'm now executing my HTA with the following line:

`createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", scriptDir & HTAPath & Elev & strParams, "", "runas", 1`. 

I'm also using *strParams* to send the scriptDir as an argument to redefine the HTA working directory which open as *C:\Windows\System32* by default.